# TypeScript that includes local JavaScript library in electron-vite fails to compile correctly

Tags: typescript, electron, vite

I am trying to import a local library into a vite-electron TypeScript project. Forgive me for my lack of understanding of vite-electron and JS bundling ecosystem, I am new to JS and TS development as of a month ago. Running `npm run dev` throws:

```
App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: _global is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jason.kinnard\winsrc\dse-auto-flash-vite\out\main\index.js:105:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:967:12)
    at l._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13642)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```

In my `src/main/index.ts`, I call `import ../globals`

```
import "../globals"
import { app, shell, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
import { join } from 'path'
import { electronApp, optimizer, is } from '@electron-toolkit/utils'
import icon from '../../resources/icon.png?asset'

function createWindow(): void {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 900,
    height: 670,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    ...(process.platform === 'linux' ? { icon } : {}),
    webPreferences: {
      preload: join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js'),
      sandbox: false
    }
  })
// etc....
```

In `src/globals.ts`, the following code gets run:

```
import "js-globals"

const _global = (global as any)
// stuff gets attached to _global further down in the file.
```

`js-globals` is a local JavaScript library I've placed in the source root dir `./lib` and installed via the following `package.json` entry:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-toolkit/eslint-config-prettier": "^2.0.0",
    "@electron-toolkit/eslint-config-ts": "^1.0.1",
    "@electron-toolkit/tsconfig": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.19.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.47",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "electron": "^28.1.1",
    "electron-builder": "^24.9.1",
    "electron-vite": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "js-globals": "file:lib/js-globals-3.13.0.tgz",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.0.11"
  }
```

My `tsconfig.node.json` looks like the following:

```
{
    "extends": "@electron-toolkit/tsconfig/tsconfig.node.json",
    "include": [
        "electron.vite.config.*",
        "src/main/*",
        "src/preload/*",
        "src/globals.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "composite": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "types": ["electron-vite/node"]
    }
}
```

So I am including `globals.ts` and allowing JS. The compiled JavaScript in `out` has `_global` in the code but no initial definition of `_global`. What could be causing this?

Note, I am open to any more acceptable ways of including a local library in a global manner in my code, I am using another non-Vite project as reference for getting this library globally into my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `js-globals` was included in `devDependencies`, not `dependencies`. The non-Vite way of electron development and running `electron /path/to/index.js` seems to permit this while allowing the app to resovle its runtime dependencies.